# Permission denied for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, permission-denied

I have a permission denied problem when I run the app in my android studio. Before that, I need to declare that my group mates can run the code and pop out the data but me, we all use the same code and version but I use a mac that they use the win system.

Below is the logcat info:

```
Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/ample.inclass0: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
W/ample.inclass0: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:660): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=857 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c151,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/ample.inclass0: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.inclass0: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1180)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:293)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdb7e2040, tid 5252
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf1f7e5c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf1f7e5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe6d24dd0)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdb7e3800, tid 5252
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff807000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf1f7e5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe6d24dd0)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
```

Below is the AndroidMainfest file:
For toolsLtargetApi="31" I tried to delete and run nothing changed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.inclass07">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.InClass07"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions to solve the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work for everyone, but I solved my problem by changing the Emulator.

Previously, I used the Nexus 5X Q(API29), but now I switched to the Nexus 5X API33 and doing so solved my problem.

I also tried others with API33 and they work just fine.